# Inno Setup disable Installing Wizard Pages

Tags: inno-setup

Is it possible to disable the the Preparing To Install `wpPreparing` and the Installing `wpInstalling` Wizard Pages (i.e. the ones with the progress bar) so that they do not show during installation? There does not appear to be a built-in directive or method (e.g. for the Ready Wizard Page you can use `DisableReadyPage=yes` to do so). Am I missing something, or is it, as I suspect, simply not possible?

I have already tried using:

```
function ShouldSkipPage(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  if CurPageID = wpPreparing then
    Result := True;
  if CurPageID = wpInstalling then
    Result := True;
end;
```

Comment: `function ShouldSkipPage(PageID: Integer): Boolean;` does not seem to work for `wpInstalling` or 'wpPreparing` (see above modified question).

Comment: The script in this case isn't actually going to install anything, it is actually just to run some code and display the result e.g. create an unlock code based on an installation ID for use in the actual installer.

Comment: You cannot skip `wpInstalling` page anyhow. It is an important page on which runs the installation itself. What would you do without it, anyway ?

Comment: As I suspected. Thanks for confirming that there is no way to disable or skip it. As described above, this particular script isn't actually going to install anything.

Comment: The you may abort before this page or you can do the checks and display message with code without the actual Wizard, just by using the `function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;`

Comment: Thanks @RobeN. That pointed me in the right direction. The easiest way around this in this use case is to simply prevent the installer from advancing any further by returning `False` in `NextButtonClick`, modifying the button labels and whether they are displayed and include set `Confirm := False;` in `CancelButtonClick`. Code snippet posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to skip the `wpPreparing` or `wpInstalling` Wizard Pages. However, if the installer is not actually installing anything and is being used to return something, say an unlock code, as is the use case here, the following could be done instead:

```
//Disable the Exit confirmation prompt
procedure CancelButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer; var Cancel, Confirm: Boolean);
begin
  Cancel := True;
  Confirm := False;
end;

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
//Get the unlock code
  if CurPageID = UnlockCodePage.ID then
    begin
      if UnlockCodePage.Values[0] = '' then
        begin
          MsgBox('You must enter an installation ID to generate an unlock code.',
            mbError, MB_OK);
        end
      else
        begin
          UnlockCodePage.Values[1] := GetUnlockCode;
        end;
      Result := False;
    end;
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
//Define button visibility, whether the Back button is enabled and change the Next and Cancel button labels
 WizardForm.CancelButton.Caption := '&Close';
 if CurPageID = UnlockCodePage.ID then
   begin
     WizardForm.BackButton.Enabled := False;
     WizardForm.NextButton.Caption := '&Generate';  
   end;
end;
```

Hopefully this may help someone looking to do something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this - DisableReadyPage=yes in the [Setup] section.

Seems the only other option is to use the "install silently" command line switch.  I'd be careful though this essentially installs a potentially destructive program without the users knowledge.

Comment: Yes, it only disables the Ready Wizard Page.